# Inserting a string in a certain colum if the row index of quantity column turns to <= 0

Tags: mysql, datagridview, sql-update, vb.net-2010

```
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        For r As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            qty = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            If DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString <= 0 Then
                Dim Query As Integer
                Query = "Update librarydb.blist SET remarks = 'Not available'  where quantity = '" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' "
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
                SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
                COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
                SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
                SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

            End If

        Next
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        MysqlConn.Dispose()


    End Try
```

I am to insert a string in the remarks column when the quantity of the selected row reach to < = 0. This doesnt work but can anyone help me hot to fix this?

Error = " Conversion from string "Update librarydb.blist SET remar" to type 'Integer' is not valid. "

Is there any other  msqlcommand to insert this?

Comment: The answer is in the error message. `Query` is of type `Integer` but on the very next line you set `Query` to a `string`, hence you cannot cast the string to type `Integer` message. Change to: `Dim Query As String`

Comment: Thanks sir, i didnt saw that.